# Show Product Description in PayPal Sandbox

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, paypal-sandbox

When i test in **SANDBOX** for buyer transactions in PayPal > Activities > Payments Sent > Transaction Details > Order Details, there is NO product **description** added. It's only added when a real order is placed. How do i test for the **description** in **Sandbox**?

See real buyer notification which includes the name and description :

[image]

However, using https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/notifications under Testing Tools > Sandbox Notifications, the sandbox notification only shows the product name NOT the description. See this image :

[image]

Using PayPal standard with WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

The description is sent by whatever PayPal integration you are using. There are many available, and there are literally tens of thousands of software implementations that have been done for most of them, so with the information provided there is no place to even begin answering the 'how' of this question.

The fact of the matter is the integration is sending the string `Test` as a description when testing in sandbox mode, and so that is what the PayPal sandbox transaction view will show. If you want to it to show something different, you (or the developer of it) need to change the PayPal integration to send some other (meaningfully descriptive to you) string as the item/description field's value when using sandbox mode.

Comment: I have updated the question. However, test is the name of the item not the description which is separate.